# Platform function HTTPPost issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am building an API call and I need to use POST. I decided to use 'Platform.Function.HTTPPost'. However, my cloudpage has 'internal server error' when I run the code.

```
var token = functionWhichRetrievesBearerToken() 
var journeyId = "X"
var journeyVersion = 1

var apiRoute = "RESTBaseURI/interaction/v1/interactions/stop/" + journeyId + "?versionNumber=" + journeyVersion

var contentType = "application/json";
var content = ""

var post = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(apiRoute, contentType, content, ["Authorization"], [token]);
```

Do you know what can cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: like @Ghingis pointed out. The `Platform.Function.HTTPPost` function has 6 required parameters and you missed the last parameter.

The header value supposes to be `Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` as the [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postStopInteractionById.html) so you would want to modify your call like this:

```
var response
var token = functionWhichRetrievesBearerToken();
    token = 'Bearer ' + token;
var journeyId = "X";
var journeyVersion = 1; 

var apiRoute = "RESTBaseURI/interaction/v1/interactions/stop/" + journeyId + "?versionNumber=" + journeyVersion

var contentType = "application/json";
var content = ""

var post = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(apiRoute, contentType, content, ["Authorization"], [token], response);
```

if I were you, I would use [Script.Util.HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.html?q=script.Util.HttpRequest) function for the REST API call since it's more robust and flexible. So it would be something like this:

```
var token = functionWhichRetrievesBearerToken();
var auth = 'Bearer ' + token;
var journeyId = "X";
var journeyVersion = 1;
var url = 'https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/stop/'+ journeyId + '?versionNumber=' + journeyVersion
var payload = ""

var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
    req.method = "POST"; /*** You can change the method here ***/
    req.postData = payload;

var resp = req.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I totally agree with Duc Le you should use `Script.Util.HttpRequest` instead of `Platform.Function.HTTPPost`.

But your actual issue is, that you missed the last parameter of [HTTPPost](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPPost.html)

I recommend you wrap your code in a try-catch block during development / in cases you get a 500, it can save you some time and might be able to give you some feedback about your issue (not in this case though). But be careful, things can work wonky, like some function does not provide a response/work/work properly, if wrapped in a try-catch.

And let me loop back to first my statement why you should use `Script.Util.HttpRequest` instead, as you can see in Duc Le's example you can set a `continueOnError` property so it won't throw an exception if the request fails, so you have a way to handle that based on the response.

(You could also wrap the line of  `Platform.Function.HTTPPost` in a try-catch block but that code will look atrocious.)

Comment: It seems I missed the last parameter in the function, thank you I will update like you pointed out in his first approach

Comment: I just noticed you only declared the variable in your response, sadly that is not enough.
It has to be an array and that array has to have at least one element.
It can be an `undefined` or anything, you can even set the length of that array to 1 "manually", but otherwise, you won't get the response from your request.
(The return value is just the status code of the response.)